# Why does the if statement always get the value of the last condition

Tags: python

```
import random

guess = input("Head or Tail? ")
head_tails = ["Head", "Tail"]

def coin_flip():
    random_number = [random.randint(0,1)]

    for rando in random_number:
        if rando == 0:
            answer =  head_tails[rando]
        elif rando == 1:
            answer = head_tails[rando]
    
    user_guess = ""

   #User_guess is always "False", even though the user(input) guessed the right outcome... 
   
    if guess == "Head" and random_number == 0:    
        user_guess = "True"  
    elif guess == "Tail" and random_number == 1:
        user_guess = "True"
    else:
        user_guess = "False"
   
    if user_guess == "True":
        print("You are right!")
        print("It was:", answer)
    elif user_guess == "False":
        print("You guessed wrong! You guessed:", guess)
        print("It was:", answer)

coin_flip()
```

Why does `user_guess` always equal `"False"`?

Comment: See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Also, note that in English, it's "heads" or "tails" (plural).

Comment: You set random_number equal to a list, and you are checking its equality with an integer, so your if and elif will always evaluate to false (a list is not an integer). I think you need ```random_number[0] ==0``` and similarly for the other condition.

Comment: Your code would work fine I think, if you took the brackets off of `random_number = [random.randint(0,1)]`, and got rid of `for rando in random_number:` (but left the `if` statements, changing them to check `random_number` instead of `rando`).

Comment: Replace the entire `for rando in random_number:` loop with `answer = head_tails[random_number]`

Comment: @RichardKYu Ahhh got it! Thank you for the tip, all I had to do was: if guess == "Head" and random_number == [0]:   Thank you so much, sat for around 1,5 hours trying all sort of things. Thanks!!!!

Comment: @jarmod  Smart!! Did not think of that, thanks for the tip I will replace it with your suggestion! :)

Comment: @RandomDavis ahh. That was my problem, so if I remove the brackets so that random_number is not a list, then: random_number == 0  will be able to be evaluated if I understand you correctly. Thanks for the help! I will fix that now! :)

Comment: @Ponta great! If you do fix it you can put the fix here as an answer and accept it, so that future viewers can potentially be helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since random_number is list, it can not be equal to an integer - a list is not an integer. To make the if-statement work, put brackets around the integers either `random_number = [0]` or `random_number = [1]` . This will work since the number is within a list, i.e. in `random_number`. You can also change `random_number` so it is not a list and therefore remove `for rando in random_number:` and change it to `answer = heads_tails[random_number]` and keep `random_number == 0`. This will work since `random_number` is not a list, thus it can be equal to an integer.